# How to check if the client is connected to the server?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm working on a remote chat server.
When I open the chat(client side) how can I check if it's connected to the server?

I don't have any idea of doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an echo service?

Or, if you're using TcpClient then it has a `client.Connected` boolean you can check